# How do I load data from an existing table to an empty table I have created? in sql?

Tags: sql, load

[Table I am getting info from has 4000+ rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MBjGn.png)I am trying to load info from a table provided by my teacher, into an empty table i have created. I keep getting errors for this i tried an insert into statement. 
it is loading it into the wrong column. And my table doesn't need nulls how do i get rid of that when trying to load? so it gives an error. when i use a where statement to ignore nulls

```
insert into [Education].[Course]
    (CourseDescription)
select (Description)
from Uploadfile.CoursesSpring2019
```

thank you!

[Table i am trying to put the data into](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1KZj.png)

Comment: Please provide the column of the table you are getting the data and the column where you wanted to insert along with both the table names

Comment: Also mention which database are you using

Comment: Also some sample data, with null values, which bothers you.

Comment: I am trying to load into the CourseDescription from the Description but the error says: cannot insert null into 'department key' & it doesnt accept nulls so insert fails' but that isnt even the column i specified for the data to go into?? similar issue when i try to load the course code